# CSS3 flex properties not working?

Tags: html, css, layout, flexbox

I'm having trouble understanding the new flex-model introduced in 2009.

There have been three mayor syntax changes, right?
I've been reading this tutorial which I think is most up-to-date.
http://css-tricks.com/using-flexbox/

It looks fine in chrome but it doesn't seem to work for firefox.
The concept is simple, I have a content box with three articles in it, one article containing a picture to the left, one with the main content (details) centered and flexible in the middle and one overview pane to the right.

If I understood correctly, this CSS file should arrange them horizontally whilst expanding the details box while it's at it.
Netbeans tells me that 'flex: 1' is an unknown property. What am I doing wrong?

```
#content { /*Eigenlijke tekst/artikels*/
    /* Oude chome, Android, Opera, IOS & safari syntax */
    display: -webkit-box;
    -webkit-box-orient: horizontal;

    /* Oude firefox syntax */
    display: -moz-box;
    -moz-box-orient: horizontal;

    /* Microsoft moet weer speciaal doen (IE) */
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    -ms-flex-orient: horizontal;

    /* Nieuwe chome syntax */
    display: -webkit-flex;
    -webkit-flex-direction: row;

    /* Nieuwste syntax */
    display: flex;
}

article {
    border: 1px solid black;
}
article[id="picture"] {
    width: 150px;
    padding: 10px;
    margin-left: -20px;
}
#content > article[id="details"] {
    -webkit-box-flex: 1;
    -moz-box-flex: 1;
    -webkit-flex: 1;
    -ms-flex: 1;
    flex: 1;
    margin-left: 10px;
    margin-right: 10px;
    padding: 10px;
}
article[id="overview"] {
    width: 225px;
    padding: 10px;
}
```

This is the HTML syntax:

```
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!--[if lt IE 7]>      <html class="no-js lt-ie9 lt-ie8 lt-ie7"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 7]>         <html class="no-js lt-ie9 lt-ie8"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 8]>         <html class="no-js lt-ie9"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if gt IE 8]><!-->
<html class="no-js">
        <!--<![endif]-->
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title>JSP Page</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/normalize.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/detailpages.css">
        <jsp:useBean id="al" scope="application" class="beans.actionlisteners" />
        <script src="js/vendor/modernizr-2.6.2.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="page_wrapper">
            <jsp:include page="header.jsp" />
            <jsp:include page="navigation.jsp" />
            <div id="content_wrapper">
                <section id="content">
                    <article id="foto">
                        <img src="img/festivals/rock_werchter_2013.png"
                             alt="Rock Werchter 2013 - afbeelding" width="140px"
                             draggable="true" ondragstart="<% al.dragstart(); %>"
                             />
                        Foto:&nbsp;&nbsp;
                    </article>
                    <article id="details">
                        <header>
                            <h2>Header van details</h2>
                        </header>
                            <p>Gegevens van festival</p>
                        <footer>
                            <h3>footer van details</h3>
                        </footer>
                    </article>
                    <article id="overzicht">
                        <header>
                            <h2>Lijsten</h2>
                        </header>
                            <p>Festivallijst & toevoegen</p>
                        <footer>
                            <h3>borderfactory dinges</h3>
                        </footer>
                    </article>
                </section>
            </div>
            <hr style="width: auto; margin-left: 20px; margin-right: 20px;" />
            <jsp:include page="footer.jsp" />
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please provide the HTML as well.  Flex is a valid property, Netbeans likely needs an update if it says it's invalid.

Comment: Hey @cimmanon, I added the HTML as you requested.

Comment: By the way, It doesn't really matter what netbeans says or does it?
I test my websites inside the browser and outside the scope of netbeans or am I wrong?

Comment: Nah, a lot of software tries to be *helpful* by warning you that it doesn't recognize the code you're using.  In this particular case, it just isn't aware of the relatively new property.

Comment: Yeah, I figured as much ;) Any ideas on problem? This topic doesn't seem to get much attention (yet).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Firefox implementation the 2009 specification (`display: box`) is quite buggy.  When an element becomes a *flex container*, it is supposed to behave like a block element in relation to surrounding elements.  The Firefox implementation acts more like a table element in that it shrinks down to the size of its children.  Adding an explicit width usually does the trick:

```
#content {
  width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: This gave me a different result. I had to set the max-width for the details article because chrome exceeds the maximum width when I define the width :(

Comment: I'll need a little more information to make adjustments:  http://codepen.io/cimmanon/pen/ehfKA